# how to define new message/generate new header in rosserial_arduino

Tags: ros, arduino, message, msg, rosserial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I kept searching through the wiki but this page was not created yet (http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosserial/Tutorials/Adding%20Other%20Messages) and I can't try it out myself, so I'm going to ask here.

in this link(http://answers.ros.org/question/11023/rosserial-and-custom-message-cannot-load-package)brice rebsamen says there's a script generating new msg type for me, where is it?

say, I want to define a new msg type new_msg::New, to publish it from PC to arduino. while I got New.h in package new_msg with the command "make" under the package, this New.h is not suitable for arduino liberary. I need a New.h file that tell arduino what the message looks like. What should I do? Thank you in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/30342/how-to-define-new-message/generate-new-header-in-rosserial_arduino/) by [AzureViolin](https://answers.ros.org/users/1837/azureviolin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 67 on 2012-03-23

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please see: http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosserial_client/Tutorials/Generating%20Message%20Header%20Files

(Note: at the bottom of the missing page you linked, you'll find some pages with similar names that it suggests.... in this case, the page I linked above was found in that list).

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2012-03-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AzureViolin](https://answers.ros.org/users/1837/azureviolin/) on 2012-03-30**:
Thanks a lot, man! I'll create the missing wiki page for other people who have met the same problem with me.

**Comment by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) on 2012-03-30**:
Rather than creating more (duplicate) pages, it would be best to fix broken links -- where did you find the link to the "missing" page?

**Comment by [AzureViolin](https://answers.ros.org/users/1837/azureviolin/) on 2012-04-01**:
I totally agree. The reason why I created a new page instead is because I can't find the old link anymore... I remembered that it was at the bottom of one of the tutorials, but I can't find it after I solved the problem. And I think this tutor should be in rosserial_arduino package for convenience.